# Adding axis titles

Tags: amcharts5

I'm migrating to amCharts5 but I'm having some issues with labelling axis. Is the following the correct way to add a title to the x axis? I'd prefer not to specify a percent and just add it to the axis container with a vertical layout etc.

```
chart.children.unshift(am5.Label.new(root, {
  text: "This is a chart title",
  fontSize: 25,
  fontWeight: "500",
  textAlign: "center",
  x: am5.percent(50),
  y: am5.percent(90),
  centerX: am5.percent(50),
  paddingTop: 0,
  paddingBottom: 0
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is odd but maybe my thoughts will help someone else: Yeah that looks good to me guy. I use a similar way. Been doing a lot with AM5 recently (multiple charts, dynamic stuff). Sometimes tough to find what you need on their docs but they have solid documentation I think. Their tutorials help a lot too. Here is their label docs if you haven't found it already:

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/common-elements/labels/

I find it's easier to run their Codepens and mess around with that code to try achieve want you want in *your* code and then incorporate it.